# How to change a anchor point of uibutton in [UIVIEW animate]?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to change a anchor point to (0,0) (it's not center.) of uibutton and rotate.

How to change a anchor point of uibutton?

```
mybutton.anchorPoint? = CGPointMake(0, 0); <= How to change?
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    mybutton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180 * M_PI / 180);
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `CALayer` has an `anchorPoint` property. You can do one of the following:

- You can either animate the layer (the anchor is by default the center of the bounds)
- You can combine a translation with a rotation transform (translate button center to origin, rotate and translate back)

EDIT:

Example: `[button.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180 * M_PI / 180)]`

Comment: You don't need to change the anchor on the layer, it's the center by default.

Comment: Is there a way that uibutton is rotate base on (0,0) point? (left bottom point)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would set it by the following

```
    [button.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y)];
```

But I'm only just playing with it myself. So not positive if it will work yet.

A